# What is the turn length in Civilization?

Tags: civilization

In the first edition of Civilization, the length of each turn varies.  It starts at 20 year before 1AD and is one year after 1900.  What is the full table of turn length?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the original Civilization, the years per turn breaks down in the following way:

- 4000 BC - 1000 AD: 20 years per turn (total of 250 turns)
- 1000 AD - 1500 AD: 10 years per turn (total of 50 turns)
- 1500 AD - 1750 AD: 5 years per turn (total of 50 turns)
- 1750 AD - 1850 AD: 2 years per turn (total of 50 turns)
- 1850 AD - End of game: 1 year per turn (total of 170 to 250 turns)

I believe that turns count for fewer years as the game progresses to simulate the accelerating technological progress of civilization - it takes us less real-world time in the modern era to make larger leaps forward than it did in previous historical eras.

The game [ends in a different year](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ1/manual/civ1_man.htm) depending on the difficulty setting:

- Chieftan - 2100 AD (total of 650 turns)
- Warlord - 2080 AD (total of 630 turns)
- Prince - 2060 AD (total of 610 turns)
- King - 2040 AD (total of 590 turns)
- Emperor - 2020 AD (total of 570 turns)

Essentially, the easier the difficulty level, the more turns you have to finish the game.